# How can I use Azure AD to authenticate for Azure .net API calls?

Tags: .net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Background: I have an Azure subscription, with users setup with the appropriate permissions via AD auth.  Everyone has the appropriate permissions to do what they need to via the Azure portal.

I'd like to automate some tasks though, CosmosDB crud documents, Blob Storage, user management (add/modify/delete) for our AD B2C, access data in Insights, and so on...  Nothing complicated.

That automation would come from a .net WPF desktop app.

**Q: How do I authenticate against the Azure AD for use in Azure API calls?**

There are plenty of seemingly solid .net APIs for Azure, but nowhere can I figure out how to authenticate via the AD of the company/subscription. Every API seems to want a certificate/secret key based connection, and I obviously can't have a secret key with god access in a distributed desktop app.  Nor do I really want to build a web/function layer to proxy the various API's. That should be unnecessary, and opens me up to security problems if my code isn't perfect.

Am I crazy for thinking this should be a default part of any Azure API?  Single sign-on was nearly a given 10+ years ago in the corporate world.  How did that not translate to the cloud by default?

Answer (score 1):

What you’re looking for is the MSAL library, authenticating to the Azure apis. Microsoft has a good docs page on how to do this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop

This article is for the graph api, but you can select the azure api set when registering the app in AD

Comment: Aah, the API Permissions on the App registration..  That's the part that's been eluding me.  Thanks.